# GUI System Implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, user-interface, drawing, x11

I'm going to make a very simple GUI toolkit. The two elements in this toolkit will be a rectangular and a circular button. I've got two questions:

---

**#1**

Would it be more efficient to have an [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) with a bitmask on the circle, a drawing index system, or something else entirely?

By 'drawing index system', I mean 'drawing' the GUI elements on a canvas acting like an input mask(each 'pixel' is either a null pointer or a pointer to a button), updating it whenever the window size changes. Whenever an input event occurs(let's say a hover event), you would:

- Get the cursor position
- Calculate the index of that point on the input canvas(like you would with an image)
- Retrieve a pointer to the respective GUI element from that index.

---

**#2**

How should elements be implemented? Essentially, how should input be handled once the element is determined? Should I:

- Draw something on the actual framebuffer, then run a callback(if pointer is present) for functionality?

or,

- Start a 'hover' callback, which may or may not decide to draw on the framebuffer.

---

I would like to avoid OOP if at all possible.

---

For anybody who thinks this question is vague, it is asking to show or find the optimal(if there is one) implementation of a simple GUI toolkit in which the only elements are a rectangular and circular button, as stated above.

Essentially, I'm asking this:

> Given a set of positions/sizes of arbitrary elements and the cursor position, what is the quickest way to determine which element the cursor is currently intersecting?

Comment: GUI toolkits is one branch of human activity where OOP seems inescapable.

Comment: Yes, however I would simply like to know the most efficient method of implementing a GUI with elements that may have a differing shape or opacity.

Comment: Neither the R-tree nor the index system look lile a good way to implement a GUI.

Comment: Then what IS a good way? How can you know if there's a problem if you don't know the solution?

Comment: Let each widget get all events from its parent and compute whether it is interested in an event or not. You may have zero, one, or more widgets reacting to an event, regardless of their visible geometry.

Comment: Seriously? A down vote without any explanation? Whoever did that, you can at least cite why.

Comment: I would guess the downwote comes from the fact that your question is very vague and doesn't admit an authoritative canonical answer, but I of course cannot read their mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create your own GUI kit you have several option available.

**1. use a third party library library:**

- I recommend [GTK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVx0R.jpg).
- And before you ask it is a library for C.
- With this library you can easily create any button .To answer your question you can use this library to raise event and create a handler.

  - For more details on this library visit [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVx0R.jpg): https://www.gtk.org/download/index.php

**2. You cant directly work with hardware by using 'dos.h' and 'graphics.h' builtin library in C:**

- Check this website for more information:
  http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-press-me-button-game

**3. Design your OWN tool kit:**

*- Detect if cursor is inside circle:*

> ```
>    (a , b) => location on circle's center
>
>    (x, y) => location of cursor
>
>    r => radius of circle
> ```

- We know that if (x, y) Is inside circle the distance between (x, y) and (a,b) should be less than the radius(r).
- If it is greater that the radius it is clear that the point (x,y) lies outside circle.
- In short distance between `(x, y) and (a, b) <= r` then they intersect

> To find distance between two points use distance formula. ie `sqrt((x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2)`.

*- Detect if cursor is inside rectangle:*

*(This was very tough, had to refer high school textbooks :-p)*

> (a, b) => center of rectangle
>
> (p, q) => any one vertex of rectangle
>
> L => length of (a, b) and (p, q)
>
> m1 => slope of L
>
> r => radius of circle enclosing the rectangle

All the above values have to calculated only once, at the time of creating rectangle.

Now values which change with cursor:

> (x, y) => position of cursor
>
> dist => distance between (x, y) and (a, b)
>
> m2 => slope of dist

To find slope of (1, 2) and (3, 4) use formula `slope(m) = (4-2)/(3-1)`

After this find the angle between line L and line dist

> o => angle between dist and L

To find angle between two lines with slopes m1 and m2 use formula:

[image]

After this using basic trigonometry we know that `z = L * cos(o)` where z is the distance shown in the diagram.

*`If z => dist` then cursor intersect else it does not.*

[image: sorry for my handwriting]

[image]

**NOTE:** *you may be wondering that is a lot of mathematics but it is the easiest way and most of the value have to be calculated only once and there is no requirement of loop so it can be done in O(1) time.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already know about GTK, Qt, wxWidgets, FLTK, and others. I'm doing this to learn the workings of GUI systems, as well as how to do it right, using the most efficient method. The reason that only those two elements will exist in my GUI is because just about every other GUI element can use it as a base.

Comment: It seems to me that 'graphics.h' is a library for DOS :/. It doesn't handle input. Rather than using a library, I want to create my own albeit simple library.

Comment: graphics.h is not a GUI kit, instead it is a standard header available in compiler.

Comment: also check this out https://www.go4expert.com/articles/mouse-programming-c-t21153/

Comment: I'm not trying to directly operate the hardware(that's the driver's job), but simply handle the input correctly. I edited my question. See the yellow section at the bottom.

Comment: So what you are asking is... Given Position on cursor is (x,y) and element center is at position (a,b)..what is the quickest way to find if cursor is In element...am I correct? @Anonymous

Comment: Yes, correct. Note that there may be buttons with truly circular input, which obviously complicates things.

Comment: @Anonymous check my edit now...does that answer your question?

Comment: Not quite. I need to be able to determine what element the cursor is in given an arbitrarily long list of rects/circles. Look, you've been trying to help so I'll mark your answer as accepted if you can find how to do it with only rectangles.

Comment: @Anonymous now? anything else ?

Comment: That answers it! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to respond earlier, I happen to be in high school :/

Comment: So @Anonymous, should this person get the 50+ reputation?

Comment: Yeah. I thought that the +50 rep was automatic. I'd upvote his post too, but I don't have enough rep on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, if you say so @Anonymous.

Comment: BTW, thank you for putting the bounty on this question!